# JavaFx - do frame to combo box

Tags: java, javafx

I have combo box and need create a frame to it. How I can add the frame below?

[image: comboBox frame]

```
ComboBox<String> combobox = new ComboBox<String>();
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "BLACK");
combobox.setItems(items);
combobox.setTranslateX(250);
combobox.setTranslateY(300);
combobox.setPromptText("Circle Color");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane Test");

//Creating StackPane
StackPane sp = new StackPane();

// add Combobox to scene
ComboBox<String> combobox = new ComboBox<String>();
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("RED", "BLUE",     "GREEN", "YELLOW", "BLACK");
combobox.setItems(items);
combobox.setTranslateX(250);
combobox.setTranslateY(300);
combobox.setPromptText("Circle Color");
sp.getChildren().add(btn);

//Adding StackPane to the scene
Scene scene = new Scene(sp,300,200);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Set the style of the combo box in an external CSS file. There are many tutorials on the Internet how to do that. For example, look [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/raw-file/3545959fa67f/modules/graphics/src/main/docs/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph). Or even simpler without an extra file [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javafx.scene.layout.Border).